# Click link should close modal and activate JavaScript to switch between hidden content sections held in divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to get something working for the last couple of days, and don't seem to be able to find a solution through searching. I've [found a fix](https://codepen.io/elmahdim/pen/azVNbN) to part of my problem which works well. However, every time I try and explain the last part of the issue, I can't seem to find the right words, so hopefully I explain it reasonably well here.

The codepen.io example is not mine, it just contains part of the fix I've used for my issue.

Please [see this page](https://stfc.ukri.org/research/science-challenges/science-challenges-new/) for where I'm currently at with the issue.

Basically, each main question has a set of sub questions. When one of these main questions gets clicked, it activates some JavaScript that hides the original content, and shows some new content. This happens for all 3 of the main questions, and reveals the sub questions. The sub questions open up in modal windows. Some of these sub questions are relevant to other sub questions, and so have links within the modal windows to switch to the relevant other sub question modal window.

I've got this working for all sub questions within the same main question section, but some of the sub questions have relevant answers in one of the other 2 main question sections. (Hopefully anyone reading this is still following.)

How do I get a link in a modal window to open up a new modal window that is held in the same page, but within a hidden section of that page?

I realise this is kind of hard to explain, so I'll try and walk you through the issue so you can see for yourself what I'm trying to achieve:

- Open link above for where the issue is currently at
- Click question C
- Click sub question C:2
- Within modal window, click 'Answer C:4' or 'Answer C:7', this is correct. If you click 'Answer A:7', it only closes the modal, and then nothing happens. How do I get this to switch to a modal (or even just the set of sub questions for question A) that's part of question A's sub questions?

Apologies for slightly confusing explanation. Please feel free to ask me for more details.

Edit 1: asked for more details, and to post some of the code. Many thanks:

Please see the following, for how the modal's are made, there are 23 modals split over 3 sections overall. The buttons in the modal footer are the things not working properly at the moment. If the link is pointing to a sub question within the same set, it works fine, but if it points to another set, it closes the modal and then nothing happens:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<ul class="nav nav-fill nav-pills">
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link subQSciCha button" data-target="#myModal15" data-toggle="modal">C:1. What are the fundamental particles and fields?</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="fade modal" id="myModal15" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header"><button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">&times;</button>
<h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="container-fluid">
<p>Stuff...</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#myModal16" data-toggle="modal" type="button">Answer C:2.</button><button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#myModal18" data-toggle="modal" type="button">Answer C:4.</button><button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Close</button></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Now for the JavaScript (this is all the JavaScript, and some of it doesn't relate to the modals, but just in case it's getting in the way):

```
// Hides the sub questions and switch menu on page load if no anchor link is used
// If anchor link is used, challenges will hide and selected question and menu will display
window.onload = function() {

// Retrieves URL # and splits into 2 IDs which are used to display relevant questions/menu
var $idNme = location.hash;
var $idNmeSplit = $idNme.split('/');
var $idQ = $idNmeSplit[0];
var $idM = "#" + $idNmeSplit[1];

if(!$idNme){
    hideAnswers()
    hideSubQuestions()
} else {
    hideAnswers()
    hideSubQuestions()
    $("#sciChallenges").children().hide();
    $($idQ).show();
    $($idM).show();
}
}

// Hides the sub questions and switch menu
function hideSubQuestions(){
$("#subQuestions").children().hide();
$("#switchMenu").children().hide();
}
// Shows the sub questions for the selected question and switch menu with a fade in set to 1 second
function showSubQuestions(i,m) {
hideAnswers();
$("#intro").hide();
$("#sciChallenges").children().hide();
$("#subQuestions").children().fadeIn(1000).hide();
$(i).show();
$("#switchMenu").children().fadeIn(1000).hide();
$(m).fadeIn(1000).show();
}
// Shows the 4 main questions when 'All Challenges' is selected
function showSciChallenges() {
hideSubQuestions();
hideAnswers();
$("#intro").fadeIn(1000).show();
$("#sciChallenges").children().fadeIn(1000).show();
}
// Hides the answers to all questions
function hideAnswers() {
$("#answersA, #answersB, #answersC").children().hide();
}
// Shows the answer to selected question
function showAnswers(a) {
$("#answersA, #answersB, #answersC").children().hide();
$(a).fadeIn(1000).show();
}
```

Let me know if you need to see more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving ALL of your modal divs to directly after your body tag.  Since the modals are hidden until you call them anyway, they don't need to be inside other divs that may be hidden.

```
<body>
<div class="fade modal" id="myModal1" role="dialog" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true"></div>
<div class="fade modal" id="myModal2" role="dialog" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true"></div>
<div class="fade modal" id="myModal..." role="dialog" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true"></div>

<div class="container">
**the rest of your content
</div>

</body>
```

then you can call any modal from inside any other modal:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#myModal7" data-toggle="modal" type="button">Answer A:7.</button>
```

Comment: Hero, this worked, many thanks and much appreciated! Genuinely been banging my head against walls trying to work it out. Work will be happy, thanks a lot!